# How to summarize days by a flag field?

Tags: sql, db2, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

How can I summarize the days Kyle has on this table using a flag field?

| Row | Name | Flag | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kyle | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | Kyle | 0 | 02 |
| 3 | Kyle | 1 | 01 |
| 4 | Kyle | 1 | 18 |
| 5 | Kyle | 1 | 01 |
| 6 | Kyle | 0 | 01 |
| 7 | Kyle | 1 | 01 |
| 8 | Kyle | 1 | 01 |

I want this result:

| Row | Name | Flag | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kyle | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | Kyle | 0 | 02 |
| 3 | Kyle | 1 | 20 |
| 6 | Kyle | 0 | 01 |
| 7 | Kyle | 1 | 02 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads like a gaps-and-island problem. If I follow this correctly, we can identify "adjacent" rows with the difference between row numbers, then aggregate islands whose flag is enabled:

```
select min(row) as row, name, flag, sum(days) as days
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by row) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by name, flag order by row) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by name, flag, 
    case when flag = 1 then rn1 - rn2 else row end
order by 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8PqnRcrF)** (credits to nbk for creating the use case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use window funtions for that

First wie need a group to group by, which the frist both CTEs will provide

```
WITH CTE As(
SELECT
     Row, Name, Flag, Days
  , CASE WHEN Flag <> LAG(Flag) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDEr By row)
  OR LAG(Flag) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDEr By row) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd rnk
FROM tab1),
CTE2 AS (SELECT
Row, Name, Flag, Days, SUM(rnk) OVER(ORDER BY row) rnk
FROM CTE)
SELECT 
    Row, Name, Flag, Days
FROM CTE2 WHERE Flag = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    MIN(Row), Name, Flag, SUM(Days) as Days
FROM CTE2 WHERE Flag = 1
GROUP BY Name,Flag, rnk
ORDER By row
```

| ROW | NAME | FLAG | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kyle | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | Kyle | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | Kyle | 1 | 20 |
| 6 | Kyle | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | Kyle | 1 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ITwG5EWv)